# django 502 bad gateway on production server with logging

Tags: django

I am trying to get logging to work, and it works on my dev environment, but when I move it to the production something goes wrong...

settings.py:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,

    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s \n%(asctime)s \n%(module)s \n%(process)d \n%(thread)d \n%(message)s\n\n'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s \n%(message)s\n\n'
        },
    },

    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'log.log'),
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },

    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Also I am using nginx/gunicorn if that makes any difference...

NGINX ERROR LOG:

```
2016/01/17 19:33:03 [error] 28809#0: *271 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: ip.ip.ip.ip, server: myserver.com, request: "GET /es/jhkjhkjh/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/es/jhkjhkjh/", host: "myserver.com"
```

I can't seem to track down the gunicorn logs right now as I have never looked at them and the /var/logs/gunicorn folder is empty...I will try to find these asap

Comment: Have you checked your nginx logs or gunicorn logs? Default nginx logs are at `/var/log/nginx/`, and gunicorn logs will depend on your configuration.

Comment: added nginx log to question, still looking for gunicorn log

Comment: How are you running gunicorn right now? gunicorn takes a `--error-logfile=<path-to-logfile>` parameter.

Comment: TBH I used digital ocean to start the django project and I am having trouble getting gunicorn to take args like it says in their docs because I don't know the appname that was used and I can't seem to find it in the system...Should be /etc/gunicorn.d/... right?

Comment: ok I am trying to get the error-logfile to work but it is causing 502's every way I try...I am not sure what is happening

Comment: POsted my nginx error log for more info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the owner and permissions of the logfiles. It needed to be set to the proper level.